# How can I get a poll to show up on facebook and a wordpress site?

Tags: facebook, wordpress

Is there a way I can get a poll to show up on both my wordpress site and facebook.

Do I need to use a facebook app?

Could I create an iframe to show up on the facebook page?

I'm not exactly sure if this poll will just show up on the homepage of a facebook page or if the poll will be something in the news feed. I am just trying to do initial research.

Most of my searched brings up polldaddy.com

I am currently using wp-polls, could I create a custom interface to have it show up on facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) [Yes](https://developers.facebook.com)

3) When creating Facebook Applications, iFrames are used by default, pointing to the location of your app on the server you specified in your Application Settings

4) Applications themselves cannot appear on a Facebook Profile page. You can generate Links and Status Messages (among other things) for users that approve your app which CAN appear in the user's Timeline/Profile Page

5) Depending on what you want to spend, [Woobox](http://woobox.com/) is a good one too.

6) Yes. Since Applications are just iFrames, you can style the page on which you want your poll to appear to look however you like. Though, on Facebook, it will still reside ONLY on its corresponding application page.

You will want to look into the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) or the [PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) for more information on how to set up a UI for your Facebook App to interact with Facebook itself.